# How to using implode from looping table in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get error

> Array to string conversion

when to implode looping from table

```
 $sql = $this->db->query('select * from TEST');

    foreach ($sql->result() AS $row){
        $array[] = array('id' => $row->id);
        $implode = IMPLODE(',',$array);
    }
//This is I'm get data from other database server(SQL server) where in 'id' from database test(local database)
        //and result query i will save to table test3(database server local)
        $query = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id IN($val)");
        $result = array();
        foreach($query->result_array() AS $row){
            $result[] = array (
                            'id' => $row['id'],
                            'nm' => $row['nm'],
                             'golcust' => $row['golcust'],
                            'golcustbi' => $row['golcustbi'],
                            'jnsbh' => $row['jnsbh']
                            );
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('test3',$result);
```

How can I fix it?
i get error 
Error Number: 37000

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4)

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/sipdn/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should investigate using prepared statements for security, if the `$implode` variable can be influenced by an attacker you will have a potential SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not seeing that when you do this:

```
$array[] = array('id' => $row->id);
```

You are assigning an array, inside another array, and the implode function is expecting an array of values, and not an array of array with values.

The answer is that you should do this

```
foreach ($sql->result() AS $row){
    $array = array('id' => $row->id);
    $implode = IMPLODE(',',$array);
}
```

Instead of this

```
foreach ($sql->result() AS $row){
    $array[] = array('id' => $row->id);
    $implode = IMPLODE(',',$array);
}
```

And the reason is that implode function firm is

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $strings )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for response. but when i use that i just get one id from table, whereas me need id from that table to query where id in from another table.

Comment: I think that you should do this in your foreach
"$array[] = $row->id;"

And later on, after the foreach do this
"$values = IMPLODE(',',$array);"

And you're done, doesnt it?

Answer (score 0):

try this, the simple code without implode and array

```
$sql = $this->db->query('select * from TEST');

$val = '';
foreach ($sql->result() AS $row){
    $val .= $row->id.',';
}
// before rtrim $val is 1,2,3,
$val = rtrim($val,',');
// after rtrim $val is 1,2,3
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id IN('".$val."')");
// finally query will be "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id IN('1,2,3')"
```

may it can help you

Comment: every use this $val .= $row->id.','; i get error A Database Error Occurred
Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/sitename/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1498. I use Codeigniter 3.

Comment: have you add initiate `$val = '';` ?.
try, change `rtrim` with `trim`. and 
Check the database.php file in application/config/
`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my_database'; // here is the database selection`

Comment: and also try to change last query `$db2->query` to `$this->db->query`

Comment: $db2->query this for setting to connect to another server database is sql server, i user odbc driver and i think this the trouble Message: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect. if try to where in same database server your code is work.

Comment: ok, then what is your id type? if int or numeric,
just remove the `'..'` (pick) and `".."` quote in 
"SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id IN(".$val.")" OR "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id IN($val)".

Comment: still error even i use "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id IN(".$val.")" OR "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE id IN($val)". the error is [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

SELECT * FROM id WHERE test IN(1,2,3,4)

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/sipdn/system/database/DB_driver.php

Comment: the problem from sql server, right ? can you show me the code, I want to know the complete query

Comment: Using implode is recommend, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: you're missing `'` pick in `golcust' => $row['golcust']` instead  `'golcust' => $row['golcust']`

Comment: that's not the problem, it is missing when iam copy the file to here

Comment: whata type of `nm, golcust, golcustbi, jnsbh` ?

Comment: so why does the error appear. Between the fields to be executed there is a string value, so you have to check what type of value it is.

Comment: nm, golcust, golcustbi, jnsbh type varchar

Comment: try this 
`'id' => (int)$row['id'],
                            'nm' => (string)$row['nm'],
                             'golcust' => (string)$row['golcust'],
                            'golcustbi' => (string)$row['golcustbi'],
                            'jnsbh' => (string)$row['jnsbh']`
 (int) will output integer and (string) will output string

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an array inside an array. `$array[] =` means create a new key in `$array` and put everything after the equal sign into that key. So you don't have to create a new array.

It is simple as this `$array[] = $row->id`.

Then `$array[0]` would be the first id that is in the database and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved I'm using query like bellow. Thanks all for response.

$sql = $this->db->query('select * from TEST');

```
    foreach ($sql->result() AS $row){
        $array[] = array('id' => $row->id);
    }

        $query = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM mCIF WHERE nocif IN ('".implode("','",$array)."')");
        $result = array();
        foreach($query->result_array() AS $row){
            $result[] = array (
                            'id' => $row['id'],
                            'nm' => $row['nm'],
                             'golcust' => $row['golcust'],
                            'golcustbi' => $row['golcustbi'],
                            'jnsbh' => $row['jnsbh']
                            );
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('test3',$result);
```